# PowerShell redirect Information Stream to Verbose Stream from inside script

Tags: powershell, runspace

I'd like to redirect the Information Stream to the Verbose Stream from **within** my executing PowerShell script (not from the PowerShell command line).

As far as I know, the only way of getting a handle on the Information Stream object is via the `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` instance. If leveraging an isolated PowerShell instance, I could add an event handler like so:

```
$psInstance.Streams.Information.add_DataAdding({
  param($sender, $e)  
  Write-Verbose $e.ItemAdded
})
```

But in my case, I'm looking to do this from the executing script....so if I could do something like:

```
$psInstance = [PowerShell]::Current
```

if the `Current` property actually existed...

So, my question is - can I get a handle on the currently executing `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` instance or in lieu of that is there another way I can redirect the Information Stream to the Verbose stream from within my executing script?

Comment: `function f { param([Parameter(Mandatory)][ScriptBlock]$SB) . { . $SB | % { $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($_) } } 6>&1 | % { Write-Verbose $_ } }`

Comment: @PetSerAl Look like you have to say `write-verbose -verbose`.

Comment: @js2010 No, if you want to use verbose preference from `$VerbosePreference` preference variable.

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1

This is an example of it.  6>&4 doesn't seem to work.

```
write-host hi 6>&1 | Write-Verbose -Verbose 4>4.txt
cat 4.txt

hi
```